# Сохранение кода и идентификатора из метода для использования в другом классе

Tags: java, rest-assured

В одном классе я получаю в методе код и идентификатор, а в другом классе надо использовать их как входные параметры. Как сохранить значение переменных smsCode и smsId для использования в другом классе?

```
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.specification.RequestSpecification;
import io.restassured.response.Response;
import io.restassured.response.ResponseBody;
import io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

class GetSmsTest
{
    Config config = new Config ();
    String smsCode;
    String smsId;
    @Test
    void getSMSTest () 
    {
        RequestSpecification request = RestAssured.given ().relaxedHTTPSValidation ();
        Response response = request.get (config.getToken);
        JsonPath jsonPath = response.jsonPath ();
        String token = jsonPath.get ("access_token");
        request.header ("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject ();
        jsonObject.put ("recipient", "9031111112");
        request.header ("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        request.body (jsonObject.toString ());
        response = request.post (config.getSMS);
        jsonPath = response.jsonPath ();
        smsCode = jsonPath.get ("code");
        smsId = jsonPath.get ("id");
    }
}


package qa.onlinebroker;

import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.specification.RequestSpecification;
import io.restassured.response.Response;
import io.restassured.response.ResponseBody;
import io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

class CheckSmsTest
{
    Config config = new Config ();

    GetSmsTest getSmsTest = new GetSmsTest ();
    @Test
    void checkSMSTest ()
    {
        RequestSpecification request = RestAssured.given ().relaxedHTTPSValidation ();
        Response response = request.get (config.getToken);
        JsonPath jsonPath = response.jsonPath ();
        String token = jsonPath.get ("access_token");
        request.header ("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject ();
        jsonObject.put ("code", getSmsTest.smsCode);
        jsonObject.put ("id", getSmsTest.smsId);
        request.header ("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        request.body (jsonObject.toString ());
        response = request.post (config.checkSMS); 
    }
}

import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.path.json.*;
import io.restassured.response.*;
import io.restassured.specification.*;

class Config
{
       void setToken (String token)
       {
        this.accToken = token;
        RequestSpecification request = RestAssured.given ().relaxedHTTPSValidation ();
        Response response = request.get (getToken);
        JsonPath jsonPath = response.jsonPath ();
        String access_token = jsonPath.get ("access_token");
        request.header ("Authorization", "Bearer " + accToken);
        }
        }
```

Comment: Записывай в стэк значений.

Comment: Записывай в стэк значений.

Comment: В смысле в стэк значений?

Comment: Ну это долго объяснять

Answer (score 0):

Попробуем прежде всего обозначить саму концепцию:

Передача данных в объект другого класса обычно делается или через конструктор (например в методе method создается объект класса B и ему передаются данные из переменных a s)

```
class A {
  int a = 1;
  String s= "str"

  void method() {
    new B(a, s)
  }
}

class B {
  int a;
  String s;

  B (int a, String s) {    //конструктор
    this.a = a;
    this.s = s
  }
}
```

или через сеттер

```
class A {
  int a = 1;
  String s= "str"

  void method() {
    B b = new B();
    b.setA(a);
    b.set(s);
  }
}

  class B {
      int a;
      String s;

    setA(int a){ // сеттер
      this.a = a
    }
    setS(int s){
      this.s = s
    }
}
```

можно выбрать один из вариантов (или оба) и несложно реализовать. если будут вопросы, спрашивай

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! С сеттерами я работал один раз. Поправьте меня, но в данном случае я понял это так. В конфиге создал метод для получения токена. Добавил в текст вопроса. Такой метод надо будет использовать в каждом тесте? Или можно просто добавлять заголовок и указывать переменную accToken?